# Javascript in firefox, opera, internet explorer, safari

Tags: javascript, web, firefox

I have a web that containing a javascript. The javascript running well in chrome but in firefox, opera, internet explorer, safari, etc not. How must I do to run javascript in all browser.?
Please, help

Comment: Test it and look for errors in the console.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no error was displayed. So, it's difficult to find out the error.

Comment: You should probably use the debugger to trace over it ans find the problem then.

Comment: What do you mean by not running well?Also post your code

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara I'll test it. Thanks bro.

Comment: @SanSolo when selecting each option, the textbox that appears does not change according to choice

Comment: i've problem with javascript.option.asyncstack. if it's set true, the js works fine but if it's set false, the js not works fine. can anyone help me with this.? please,